# Multiprocessing using Pipe or Queue

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I have a requirement where I am going to receive  asynchronous data (JSON) from client over http, which I've to process whenever it is received and then send it to a device over TCP connection, and get the responses back (1 or 2 responses based on request). This response I have to send it to client back.

- My question is how can I do that? i.e. should I run to `while True:` loop and wait for data is put on the `Queue`, by keep checking it if it is not empty, once received , I will collect data from `Queue` and send it over TCP, But how second loop (recv data from TCP connection) should be run? Same `while True:` loop for waiting for TCP response? and once response is received how do I send it to HTTP client?
- If yes, then how will it work?  Can someone provide an example? I thought running two processes, one for `write_to_queue` and `read_from_queue`, but still can't comprehend how to implement and how will it work.

Comment: Multiprocessing is not involved here.  You will have an HTTP server (which is usually done with a framework like Flask or Django)  When the client sends you a new request, your handler will make a TCP connection to the device, send the data, receive the response, and send it to the HTTP client.  Your HTTP handler cannot return until you get the answer.  This is all synchronous processing.

Comment: I am running flask, and can put each request in a queue and deliver to TCP server one by one, but  for ex. I've received 5 simultaneous request from client, I put them in a queue, now when I'm delivering each one by one to TCP server, I've to receive responses  from TCP server. i.e.,  when I deliver 3rd request, I must have got responses of first request., how to handle this?  which means one process should keep sending requests to TCP server and another keep receiving responses from it. Please let me know how this can be achieved.

Comment: This TCP server process the received request and return the response in 10/20/30 seconds according to the parameter value in tcp request.

Comment: Your flask request handler will have to block to wait for the TCP server.  You can't allow the request handler to return, because that ends the response.  There's nothing to synchronize here.  Each HTTP request sends a request to your TCP server and blocks waiting for the response.  One in, one out.